# Chronicle Queue Does Not Release First File

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I've been experimenting with Chronicle Queue 4.5.27. We are running some tests on a Windows 7x64 VM (Java x64) and sometimes it seems like Chronicle Queue will not ever release the first file that it creates.

We are configured with MINUTELY roll cycles. 1-3 threads can write and there is a single consumer processing on the other end.  I register a `StoreFileListener` to listen for the `onReleased` event and I groom the file from there (on Windows it tries a few times because of the known issue with mmap files).

The issue is that I never get a notification about the first file the queue creates and a heap dump shows that someone is holding on to the MappedByteBuffer; otherwise the Queue is working as expected. Is there any reason this might happen?

E.g. I'll see something like this on disk after a while:

20170705-2000.cq4
20170705-2008.cq4
20170705-2009.cq4

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

( I think ) This is now fixed in the latest version.

Comment: So this is a known issue? Are there any other cases where a file may not be released and if so are they fixed in the latest version?

Comment: @akagixxer there was cases with ThreadLocal references were holding onto the files. This is fixed in the version available in github.

Comment: which is the fixed version number ?